# how to create, fill and search on iphone xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk, nsmutablearray

`enter code here`hi hackers :) I'm programming in xcode iphone sdk and this is my problem:

imagine that I have images (sprites) and their locations (x and y) and I would like to find which image is for example on x=150 and y = 104..

in mySQL I will do

1) table with: image name, x, y
insert (sprite1.png, 150,104)
insert (sprite2.png, 104,390) ..etc

and then search

if x=150 and y = 104 -> I got sprite1.png .. etc..

but HOW to do that on iphone? of course I wouldn't use mySQL, I need NSMutableArray or NSArray, right? but

1) which array use? (NSMutable?)
2) how to create name,x,y in it?
3) how to fill it?
4) how to search by x,y and get name?

can you help me with that? just for 2 example sprites.. thank you! :)

edit: the fourth will be pointer? for accessing image.. so I would like to have name, x,y,pointer

edit2: I got this, is it right way?

```
name = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
x = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
y = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
images = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right you will use an array.
define a data structure for it as an objective c class.
this will be your modal class with image, x, y information.
then make an array of objects of this class.

Then in a "for in" loop look for each object in the array with the required values.

e.g:

```
for(MyModalClass *modalClass in objectArray){
  if(modalClass.x == reqXVal && modalClass.y == reqYVal && modalClass.image == reqImageVal)
//Do what you want!
}
```

Comment: thank you @Apple_iOS0304 but frankly - I'm not sure how to define a data structure.. `struct images {
    int xaxiss;
    int yaxiss;
    string name;

};


names = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

//start of loop when creating images adding this info into struct?
    struct images imagesAll;
    imagesAll.xaxiss = 130;
        imagesAll.yaxiss = 120;
      imagesAll.name = Image1.png;
names addObject:[images]]; //add to NSMutableArray??`

//end of loop when adding images

is this correct way to store data? I'm really beginner with this...

Comment: what i mean by a data structure here is make an objective C class. Right click on the file hierarchy on your xcode project in the left Panel of your Xcode IDE and add new file. from there add a new objective c class which inherits from NSObject. now use this class's object to have 3 properties: urX, urY and urImage. thus you will b able to store the data in such class object and make an array of such class object. I hope I clarified my self, If not then please let me know.